# freehand cropping in ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to take an image of a person using camera and then edit the image in an app. The app should have a feature to crop(preferably freehand crop) the person only leaving the background so that I am able to use the person on different backgrounds. I am not sure how to do the cropping part.. kindly help me in ios

Answer (score 2):

I created a freehand crop tool which should fit your needs.

https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface

Answer (score 0):

i have used this code for hand cropping the image . i used it for still UIView not with camera image but it will be work for any type of UIViews. Here startX,startY, endX and endY are integer values taken in toucheBegan, touchMove and touchEnd functions. hopefully it will be helpful for you.

Thanks

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       if(self.isRetina){
         contentRectToCrop = CGRectMake(startX*2, startY*2, (endX*2-startX*2), endY*2-startY*2);
       }else{
        contentRectToCrop = CGRectMake(startX, startY, (endX-startX), endY-startY);
              }
      CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], contentRectToCrop); 
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Comment: I tried but resolution of cropped image is too poor comparing to original image, is there any solution kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are not using correct checking of retina display . The above function calculate cropped image in pixels . i face the same problem initially but this code solve my problem please use this function with previous code and problem will be solved.

```
-(BOOL)isRetina
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sir,I am using ipad 1 and ipad 2, these are not retina resolution, but images appear blur